# How to make a FLAT normal on a non-flat surface so it results to Toon shading? (Example Provided)

Tags: modeling

I have a mesh of a face that i would like to shade on other Engine such as Unity. And i would like to get the shading of the face to be a super flat toon.
I tried everything on Alt-N to make the normal "gone" on the mesh of the face

What i have currently(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw21V.jpg)
[image: 1]

What i look foward to make(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QytnV.jpg)

[image: 2]
How do u achieve a seemingly "no normal" like this, i dont even think i should call it "flat" normal since it doesnt even give a sense of depth.
I could shade it on Unity with no feathering at all, or even no shadow at all. I'm just wondering how does one achieve this "no sense of depth" "no normal" on Blender with no shading, Both image above is shown in "Solid" viewport with no textures at all.
I am new to the board, sorry for the oopsies

Thank you

Comment: Maybe use a mix between a Diffuse and an Emission node? Or if you use a Principled BSDF it would mean increase the Emission Strength a bit

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i could shade it on Unity with no feahtering at all, or even no shadow at all. I'm just wondering how does one achieve this "no sense of depth" "no normal", Both image above is shown in "Solid" viewport with no textures at all.

Comment: i think an emission shader is definitely the way forward, but if for some reason you want that effect in solid view, you can change the Lighting in Viewport Shading options to Flat